# Latest Android Emulators: HTTPS Network Issues - Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl, networking, encryption

I recently updated my android SDK Tools and I am encountering the following network error in the chrome browser on the android emulators.

```
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

This issue occurs on GET requests to HTTPS endpoints that return a status of 200. I am thinking it is an encryption issue. When I start the emulator I see

emulator: WARNING: encryption is off

so I am curious if this has anything to do with it?

I have tried multiple android OS images (6.0, 7.0 on  x86 and x86_64) as well as various chrome APK versions(55, 56, 57, 58) but the issue seems to be present on all combinations I've tried.

When I run the emulator set up with Charles Proxy I do not encounter these issues. These errors are also **NOT** present on my older android emulators using older sdk versions.

Android SDK Versions  (**not working**)
SDK Platform Tools **25.0.5**
SDK Toolsm **26.0.1**
Emulator **26.0**

Android SDK Versions (**working**)
SDK Platform Tools **24.0.4**
SDK Tools **25.2.2**
Emulator - included in platform tools

Has anyone else seen network issues with the latest versions of android emulators and tools?

Are there any settings I am missing to get HTTPS requests working without a proxy on these newer emulators?

**UPDATE** - tried with a fiddler 4 proxy and see the same issue
**UPDATE 2** - also seeing this occasionally 
`net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: I doubt this is an encryption issue because chunked encoding has nothing to do with encryption. I'd rather suggest that your web server is sending broken HTTP and that newer Android SDK are less tolerant against this. And Charles Proxy is just implicitly fixing this because this is essentially an application level gateway. With this theory you should see this error only with some (broken) sites but not in general.

Comment: thanks, yeah i just tried with a fiddler proxy and see the same error. I've tested this on a couple real android devices(android 6.0.1 ), im now curious if this would be present on newer android phones.

Comment: do you think its possible that the emulator could be breaking these chunks of data?

Comment: Again, I think that is a problem of a broken server and not a problem on the client side. Only that previous implementations of the SDK were more tolerant regarding broken servers. So does it happen with a specific server only or does it happen with many servers on the internet?

Comment: I've only seen it with 1 server so far but I haven't tried very many.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Android emulator that was [fixed on 2019-05-10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/1a15692cded92d66dea1a51389a3c4b9e3b3631a). It is not available yet in any public builds.

Comment: For anyone who finds this post and wants to know since when the fix was included, it was in the Emulator 29.0.11 Stable build from May 29 (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/emulator-29011-stable.html). I don't know why you couldn't find it available on Jul 8 though.

Comment: As of today Nov. 18 2019 and having tested the latest Android Q / API Level 29 x86_64 API / Android 9.+ (Google APIs) image, the issue still happens for me. My use case: HTTP requests from Ionic 4 app, from the underlying WebView, using the provided livereload, which relies on request proxying as described in your commit. Is there a way to know if and when your commit will be available in a public build, and why it is shown in the link I posted above but doesn't seem to work?